# Python: sorting time series values

Tags: python, sorting

I have a discrete time series of values `z` recorded at different time `t`. My data looks like the following

```
z = array([3, -2, -5,  8,  7, -1])
t = array([2,  0,  1,  4,  5,  3])
```

I would like to sort the values over the time. What I am doing is the following but it is a very slow process

```
A = pd.DataFrame()
A['t'] = t
A['z'] = z
A = A.sort(columns=['t','z'])
A = A.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use numpy's [`argsort`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html):

```
>>> t = array([2,  0,  1,  4,  5,  3])
>>> indices = np.argsort(t)
>>> print(z[indices])
[-2 -5  3 -1  8  7]
```